# controlling sendinput mouse movement speed

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, sendinput

Is it possible to control the speed of the mouse pointer when using Sendinput method?

For example this is my code:

```
    public static void ClickMouseDOWN(int x, int y)
    {
        INPUT mouseInput = new INPUT();
        mouseInput.type = (int)InputType.INPUT_MOUSE;
        mouseInput.mi.dx = CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateX(x);
        mouseInput.mi.dy = CalculateAbsoluteCoordinateY(y);
        mouseInput.mi.mouseData = 0;

// mouse teleports instantly
            mouseInput.mi.dwFlags = (int)MOUSEEVENTF.MOVE | (int)MOUSEEVENTF.ABSOLUTE;
            SendInput(1, new INPUT[] { mouseInput }, Marshal.SizeOf(mouseInput));
// mouse teleports instantly

        mouseInput.mi.dwFlags = (int)MOUSEEVENTF.LEFTDOWN;
        SendInput(1, new INPUT[] { mouseInput }, Marshal.SizeOf(mouseInput));

    }
```

Following code executes MouseMovement + Mouse Button Press (down) command, but the problem is that the pointer teleports at the position (int x, int y) instead of moving to it at some constant speed.

I want to be able to control that speed.

Comment: Not sure there's much point to it but you would need a Timer to call SendInput() multiple times to animate the cursor.  Do expect the user to mess with it and move the mouse on purpose.  Well, I would.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer so in the end I had to use a native method:

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
```

i can specify `Thread.Sleep(Z)` when moving the cursor to new position

Comment: FYI: You have been using a native function before and now you're using a non-native property.